# Optimizing SQL Script

Tags: sql, ssis

I don't know how to call it, maybe its laying around here somewhere at SO...

I was thinking which one is faster and more easier to maintain..

Say, I have 50 variables where each variable gets its value from a table such as

```
SET @Location = SELECT location FROM params WHERE TYPE = 'Param'
```

vs.

```
SET @Location = 'D:\OUTBOX\'
```

Which one is optimized and will give a boost during the query execution, also, is there a way to analyze a query aside from using SQL analyzer + SQL Execution plan?

Comment: The difference in performance between using a small `params` table or putting the values directly in the code is going to be very, very small.  Issues like maintainability are more important.  I prefer to have parameter tables, so the values can be changed in SQL rather than in SSIS.

Comment: what if its not just one row?, what if the situation was for every variable value is coming of from a row? that would basically mean that you have to do 50 selects stmt? would you suggest putting all the values in one row with 50 columns?

Comment: . . 50 columns would make little difference.  The parameter table would be loaded into memory, probably on a single page. If you have an index on `type`, then the lookup will be quite fasat.  Not as fast as a constant, but probably immaterial to a script that takes a noticeable (> 100 ms) amount of time.

Comment: Hi Gordon, just to finalize my solution, let me reiterate if I understand you correctly, you were trying to tell me that I can go with the table driven variables instead of constant variables?

Comment: . . It is impossible to say without understanding the application.  I would be much more careful for a high-throughput transactional system than for a reporting system.  But using a table is reasonable under most querying circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the second one is obviously faster because it doesn't read any data, but can it work for you? It's also obviously harder to maintain. First one with simple select, should not cause any performance issues though.

If all your variables are from the same row in table you can read them with one `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT @Location = location, @Param2 = Column2, @Param3 = Column3 FROM params WHERE TYPE = 'Param'
```

Comment: what if its not just one row?, what if the situation was for every variable value is coming of from a row? that would basically mean that you have to do 50 selects stmt? would you suggest putting all the values in one row with 50 columns?